# How to make a flex-box container smoothly resize when items are not rendered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations, css-transitions

I want to create a transition for an auto height in a flex-box container.
I have a user bar with name, points, status and alert.

The alert message sometimes is rendered sometimes is not. It uses a `display: none`
What I'm trying to achieve is to resize smoothly the height of the flex-box container with a transition when I click on the alert message.

Here is a basic example (not working)

```js
const $user_alert = document.querySelector('user-alert')

$user_alert.onclick = () => {
    $user_alert.classList.add('hide')
  setTimeout(() => $user_alert.classList.remove('hide'), 1e3)
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

user-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

user-alert {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<user-bar>
  <user-name>Albert Einstein</user-name>
  <user-points>10000</user-points>
  <user-status>on</user-status>
  <user-alert>Time to Party Hard</user-alert>
</user-bar>
```

I cannot figure out how to create a simple transition without defining heights for each element inside the user bar... maybe it's not possible using `display: none`.

Any help or idea will be really appreciate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Opacity transition with display: none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000697/css-opacity-transition-with-display-none)

Comment: There will be no need for animation, just replace `display: none;` or `.hide` class to `  visibility: hidden;`. This might help: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/zYKJbPq

Comment: Manas, that's an alternative, thanks. I would like to avoid keeping the space of the user alert message.

Comment: disinfor, that answer is focus on the element that has `display: none`, thanks but I would like to resize container's height smoothly, independently of its items transitions or maybe cannot go independently.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `dispaly: none` to `transform: scale(0)`
2. In addition to `display: flex` add `transform: scale(1)`
   Let us know if that worked!

Comment: Thank you so much, great answer but I'm not allow to change `display: none` in that component

Comment: Vote up for a grate answer:)

Comment: no problem with that but could you help me? keeping the `display: none`

Comment: You cannot have transition on a boolean property. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property